# Why isn't my callback on the array working?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, callback, higher-order-functions

I wrote the code to iterate through a given array and then invoke the function subtractTwo on each element. However, when I run the function **map** the array argument returns unchanged. Does anyone know why this might be?

````
// create the subtractTwo function, callback function 
function subtractTwo (number) {
    return number - 2; 
}

// create higher-order function, map 
function map (array, callback) {
  // initiate a for loop, looping through the array and invoking the callback on each element; 
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i ++) { 
    callback(array[i]);
    
  }
  //return the new array
  return array;
}


//console.log(subtractTwo(4));
// Uncomment these to check your work!
console.log(typeof subtractTwo); // should log: 'function'
console.log(typeof map); // should log: 'function'
console.log(map([3,4,5], subtractTwo)); // should log: [ 1, 2, 3 ]```
````

Comment: your `map` is wrong because it assumes that `callback` mutates each element of the array. Not only does `subtractTwo` not do this, no function that acts on a primitive value (such as a number or string) can do this. `map` should build a new array and return that.

Comment: I should note that the exercise forbids use of the .forEach and .map methods

Comment: @RobinZigmond Thank you, I assume this means primitive values are immutable.

Comment: You’re not using the return value of `callback`. You’re calculating `array[i] - 2`, and then do nothing with the result.